agregar archivos en C++ en un mismo proyecto Visual Studio
he instalado Visual Studio para c++ pero he no entendido como agregar archivos en un mismo projecto de C++. cada vez que intento agregar un archivo no se ejecuta, o solo ejecuta el anterior archivo e incluso intente agregar un subproyecto dentro del proyecto principal pero no me ejecuta el archivo. me gustaria que los archivos esten en una sola carpeta o que cada proyecto tenga varios archivos. no se si pueda, asi como otros lenguajes de programacion como lo es Python o Java.




¿A qué te refieres con "no se ejecuta el archivo"?

Técnicamente, sí, puedes tener muchos archivos en una misma carpeta que no formen parte de un mismo proyecto. Así como ejecutas un script de Python desde la terminal:
python script.py

También puedes "ejecutar" un archivo de C++. En realidad no ejecutas archivos de C++, sino que primero los compilas y después lanzas el ejecutable. Por ejemplo con el compilador gcc:
g++ archivo.cpp -o ejecutable
./ejecutable

Visual Studio es un IDE y trabaja con soluciones y proyectos, no con archivos individuales.
Cada solución puede tener múltiples proyectos.
Cada proyecto de C++ puede estar compuesto por más de un archivo de código fuente que se combinan para formar un binario, ya sea un ejecutable o una librería. Por lo tanto, en un proyecto no puedes tener múltiples archivos con las mismas funciones (mismo nombre, parámetros y tipo de retorno) sin excluir algunos del proceso de compilación.
En una solución de Visual Studio puedes hacer clic derecho sobre uno de los proyectos y compilarlo, limpiarlo, ejecutarlo, entre otras opciones.
Si quieres que la próxima vez que presiones el botón superior de depurar o ejecutar: selecciona el proyecto, dale clic derecho y elige la opción Set as Startup Project.
Visual Studio tiene muchos parámetros más para modificar. Si das clic derecho a la solución y eliges propiedades, verás que puedes cambiar dependencias o la forma de determinar cuál proyecto se ejecutará.
